# Error shown when I want to design a view in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

I have a view in SQL Server 2008 but when I want to design it, I get this error:

[image]

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlvv8.png)

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Regretfully my magic glass bulb is broken so I have to ask you to show me the SQL code you are using...

Comment: The designer only supports a limited subset of TSQL. Looks like you are using something not supported. E.g `row_number`.